# Expiration date of an F-1 visa: Determine from I-94 or I-20?

Tags: united-states, immigration

Currently I'm in a valid **F-1** visa status. But what is the expiration date for this visa. One way to determine that is to look at `I-94` which in my case states "`D/S` (**Duration of Stay**)". The other way look at `I-20` which in my case states `August 20, 2022`.

So, I'm wondering which one of these two dates accurately expresses the expiration date of my **F-1** visa status?

Answer (score 1):

"D/S" means "duration of status" not "...of stay."  So it's not particularly helpful in determining how long your status lasts; it just means that you may remain in the US while your status lasts.

The I-20 is more helpful, but it's still not the whole story.  If you fail to comply with the conditions of your status, for example, perhaps by withdrawing from your program of study, your status ends.